# How to disable a Javascript Function when a different one is Enabled?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, jquery-events

I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    function Fos(buttonSel, inputSel, someValue, cssProperty) {
        $(buttonSel).click(function(){   
            var value = $(inputSel).attr("value");
            $("div.editable").click(function (e) { 

                e.stopPropagation();

                showUser(value, someValue, this.id)
                var css_obj={};
                css_obj[cssProperty]=value;
                $(this).css(css_obj);  
            });        
        });        
    }
```

Here are three places where function is written:

```
Fos('#border_button', '#border-radius', 2, '-webkit-border-radius');
Fos('#background_color_button', '#background-color', 1, 'background-color');
Fos('#opacity_button', '#opacity', 3, 'opacity');
```

---

```
<input type="text" id="border-radius" value="20px">
<div id="border_button">BORDER RADIUS</div>
<input type="text" id="background-color" value="red">
<div id="background_color_button">Background</div>
<input type="text" id="opacity" value=".5">
<div id="opacity_button">Opacity</div>
```

---

```
<div id="2" class="defaultclass editable" style="<?php getStyle('2') ?>">
    something
</div>
```

When you click the DIV with the ID= "border_button", or "background_color_button", or "opacity_button"
it waits for you to click any DIV with `class="editable"`, ...`$("div.editable").click(function (e) {`... it executes the function with those parameters.

**I just need a fix that will only allow ONE function with the parameters to be enabled at one time.**

Currently, when you click on all three divs with ID = "border_button", or "background_color_button", or "opacity_button" AND THEN on a div with class="editable", it executes the function with ALL THREE sets of parameters.

This is bad. I can't figure it out.

Comment: The inputs' value is run in the function after the div with id= "something_button" is clicked.

Comment: here is the HTML for a div you can click on:

<div id="2" class="defaultclass editable" style=" <?php getStyle('2') ?> ">something</div>

Comment: the PHP in there is separate from my question of course

Comment: Could you please also post the code where your `Fos` function is called from? You can actually edit your original post -- codes appear formatted there.

Comment: If you could edit this question and add in the complete html markup that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be binding and rebinding the same functions over and over, which is probably why you have that `e.stopEventPropagation` in there. Try assigning the events once and then managing the current state (which button is active) and going from there:

```
var $currentInput = null;

$("#border_button,#background_color_button,#opacity_button").click(function() {
    if ($currentInput == null) {
        $currentInput = $(this).prev();
    }
});

$("div.editable").click(function(e) {
    if ($currentInput == null)
        return;

    $(this).css(GetCssProperties());
    showUser($currentInput.val(), /* where does someValue come from? */, this.id)
    $currentInput = null;
});

function GetCssProperties() {
    if ($currentInput == null) return null;

    var value = $currentInput.val();

    if ($currentInput.attr("id") == "border-radius") return {
        "-webkit-border-radius": value
    }
    if ($currentInput.attr("id") == "background-color") return {
        "background-color": value
    }
    if ($currentInput.attr("id") == "opacity") return {
        "opacity": value
    }
}
```

---

working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/HUJ5A/

Comment: Great!

But how would I integrate this:

showUser(value, someValue, this.id)

if I have no parameters?

Comment: were you generating these `Foo` calls dynamically? where does the `someValue` value come from?

Comment: Fos('#opacity_button', '#opacity', 3, 'opacity');

Comment: someValue is the parameter #3 in the funciton

Comment: the showUser function is just a function that runs some ajax to send the parameters (value, someValue, this.id) to a PHP page to be stored in a mySQL database.

Comment: what is `someValue`? what does it relate to? Can it be managed outside of the jQuery functionality? Is it the current user id or something?

Comment: that was great for you to write that for me.

Comment: @user once I figured out kind of what you were doing it was pretty easy to write. What you were doing was rebinding that same event to all buttons and then each time the button was clicked it would rebind that same `.editable` click event over and over and over again. What I did was just abstract out what you were doing into 2 click events. It can probably be much better than what I came up with but I don't know enough about what you're doing. That said, you are welcome.

Comment: It works great. I am building off of that foundation to implement the other things I want to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "disable" a function, but you can set a variable that will force it to exit right away:

```
 var stopMe = true

 function myFunction() {

   if(stopMe) {

      return;

   } 

  ...

 }
```

Comment: How would I integrate this in to my function? I want only one of the sets of parameters to run the function at one time. Currently, when you click their enabling "divs" they all await a click to a div with class="editable". thank you

Answer (score 0):

Run the function for tag with a specific class. And a the end of the function remove this class from the tag.

```
jQuery(".myclass").click(function(){
/* do something */ 
jQuery(this).removeClass('myclass');

});
```

Comment: But if the class is removed then this method will only work once correct? I want to be able to click multiple divs with class="editable", If I remove the class I will only be able to click one div with class="editable"

Comment: Using `jQuery(this).removeClass('editable')` in the callback the class will be removed only for the clicked div.
If I wanted to remove the editable class everywhere I would have typed `jQuery('.editable').removeClass('editable')`

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell everything from your question. But this part `$("div.editable").click(function (e) {` will bind multiple click events to `div.editable` each time the user clicks `Foo arugments[0]` or `buttonSel`.

Comment: @user720785 - Yes, but I would think you are trying to do something more like `$(this).next('div.editable').click` or `prev` relative to the current element.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a pssible solution:

- Have a global variable (or HTML hidden input) say, lastDivClicked, to store the id of the recently clicked div
- Update lastDivClicked everytime one of those three divs are clicked upon
- Change your function to this:

  function Fos(inputSel, someValue, cssProperty) {

  ```
    var buttonSel = $('#lastDivClicked').val();
    $(buttonSel).click(function(){ ... }
  ```

  }